# dynamically populate hashmap with human language dictionary for text analysis

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, nlp

I'm writing a software project to take as input a text in human language and determine what language it's written in.

My idea is that I'm going to store dictionaries in hashmaps, with the word as a key and a bool as a value.

If the document has that word I will flip the bool to ture.

Right now I'm trying to think of a good way to read in these dictionaries, put them into the hashmaps, the way I'm doing it now is very naieve and looks clunky, is there a better way to populate these hashmaps?

moreover, these dictionaries are huge. maybe this isn't the best way to do this, i.e. populate them all in succession like this.

I was thinking that it might be better to just consider one dictionary at a time, and then create a score, how many words of the input text registered with that document, save that, and then process the next dictionary. that would save on RAM, isn't it? Is that a good solution?

The code so far looks like this:

```
static HashMap<String, Boolean>  de_map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
static HashMap<String, Boolean>  fr_map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
static HashMap<String, Boolean>  ru_map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
static HashMap<String, Boolean> eng_map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    ArrayList<File> sub_dirs = new ArrayList<File>();

    final String filePath = "/home/matthias/Desktop/language_detective/word_lists_2";

    listf( filePath, sub_dirs );

    for(File dir : sub_dirs)
    {
        String word_holding_directory_path = dir.toString().toLowerCase();



        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( dir ));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            //System.out.println(line);
            if(word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/de/") )
            {
                de_map.put(line, false);    
            }
            if(word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/ru/") )
            {
                ru_map.put(line, false);
            }
            if(word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/fr/") )
            {
                fr_map.put(line, false);
            }
            if(word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/eng/") )
            {
                eng_map.put(line, false);
            }
        }
    }
```

So I'm looking for advice on how I might populate them one at a time, and an opinion as to whether that's a good methodology, or suggestions about possibly better methodologies for acheiving this aim.

The full programme can be found [here on my GitHub page](https://github.com/h1395010/language_detective).

27<sup>th</sup>

Comment: I would suggest, if you have texts that you already know the language, to train a Bayesian model or a SVN model using some Machine Learning library in JAVA, that would be a little bit more effective.

1. Remove stopwords
2. Tokenize the text in unigrams and bigrams
3. Train the model
4. Check precision

Comment: That sounds good. Do you have a reference on how I might achieve that? Like a tutorial or some documentation?

Comment: I don't actually think removing stop words is a good idea. Consider 'le' 'la' 'die' 'der' 'das' 'the' those are very strong language indicators, don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task of language identification is well researched and there are a lot of good libraries. 
For Java, try [TIKA](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/tika/tika_language_detection.htm), or [Language Detection Library for Java](https://code.google.com/p/language-detection/) (they report "99% over precision for 53 languages"), or [TextCat](http://textcat.sourceforge.net/), or [LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/langid/read-me.html) - I'd suggest to start from the 1st, it seems to have the most detailed tutorial.

If you task is too specific for existed libraries (although I doubt this is the case), refer to this [survey paper](http://ojs.academypublisher.com/index.php/jetwi/article/viewFile/jetwi0604388400/10599) and adapt closest techniques.

If you do want to reinvent the wheel, e.g. for self-learning purposes,  note that identification can be treated as a special case of text classification and read this basic [tutorial for text classification](http://jmgomezhidalgo.blogspot.ru/2013/04/a-simple-text-classifier-in-java-with.html).